# Matching numbers in String using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to parse the value of `@id` from inside an `xPath` expression like:

```
"/hrdg:data/hrdg:meeting[@code='30J7Q']/hrdg:event[@id='2545525']/hrdg:selection[@id='31192111']"
```

I have written this regular expression, and am using thefollowing code for matching:

```
 Pattern selectionIdPattern = Pattern.compile(".*/hrdg:selection[@id=\'(\\d+)\'].*");
 // Grab the xPath from the XML.
 xPathData = // Loaded from XML..;
 // Create a new matcher, using the id as the data.
 Matcher matcher = selectionIdPattern.matcher(xPathData);
 // Grab the first group (the id) that is loaded.
 if(matcher.find())
 {
     selectionId = matcher.group(1);
 }
```

However `selectionId` does not contain the value after `@id=`.

**Example of Desired Outcome**

For example, with the above statement, I want to get:

```
"/hrdg:data/hrdg:meeting[@code='30J7Q']/hrdg:event[@id='2545525']/hrdg:selection[@id='31192111']"

Data I want: 31192111
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `[` and `]`, as these are also regex characters.

And if you're doing `find` (as opposed to `matches`), you may as well take out `.*` at the start and the end.

Regex:

```
"/hrdg:selection\\[@id='(\\d+)'\\]"
```

Comment: `Pattern.compile("/hrdg:event\\[@id='(\\d+)'\\]/")` since you have to escape the \ to be valid in a `String`. `'` needs no escaping.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "/hrdg:data/hrdg:meeting[@code='30J7Q']/hrdg:event[@id='2545525']/hrdg:selection[@id='31192111']";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=selection\\[@id=')\\w+(?='])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Output : 31192111

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) characters `[` and `]` in the regular expression used in `Pattern` `selectionIdPattern`

```
String xPathData = "/hrdg:data/hrdg:meeting[@code='30J7Q']/hrdg:event[@id='2545525']/hrdg:selection[@id='31192111']";
Pattern selectionIdPattern = Pattern.compile(".*/hrdg:selection\\[@id=\'(\\d+)\'\\]");
Matcher matcher = selectionIdPattern.matcher(xPathData);
if (matcher.find()) {
     String selectionId = matcher.group(1); // now matches 31192111
     ...
}
```

Since [`Matcher#find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) does partial matches, the wilcard characters `.*` can also be removed from the expression

- [Demo](http://ideone.com/xrqG9J)

Answer (score 1):

The [] characters are indicating to match a character out of those in between.  You'll need to escape the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

If your all Strings like this, you can try this

```
 String str="/hrdg:data/hrdg:meeting[@code='30J7Q']/
    hrdg:event[@id='2545525']/hrdg:selection[@id='31192111']";
 int index=str.lastIndexOf("@id");
 System.out.println(str.substring(index+5,str.length()-2));
```